# Changing Menu name

Tags: html, css

Its too much code to paste here so, I have created demo please have a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fFRGg/1/)

My question is, I'm trying to change the name of the Menu from `"Home"` to `"My Home"` its quite very simple but I have already spent good amount of time figuring out but no avail....

Yes, I have debugged using firebug too...

//html

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="header">                
                <ul class="menu">                        
                    <li class="home"><a href="" title="Downloads" class="title">My Home</a></li>
                    <li class="genres"><a href="#"  class="title">TEST 123</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//css:
please see the demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an image:

http://www.mp3mixx.com/i/menu.png

CSS:

```
.menu li a.title 
{
    text-indent:-9999em; 
    display:block;
    height:11px;
    background:url('http://www.mp3mixx.com/i/menu.png') no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The text is there for accessibility and/or search engine optimization.

Comment: So, what do I need to change?... have same exact image with different name?

Comment: You need to edit or create a new image with the text you want. Or don't use images and just use text.

Answer (score 0):

The text isn't shown; it's a background image. You'd have to change the background image to change the text.